# How to use expression in Informatica Lookup Transformation?

Tags: lookup, informatica

I want to match the last 16 characters of `emailid` in lookup source in Informatica PowerCenter Designer.

How do I do that? I *can't* use expressions in lookup.

Comment: You can override the SQL query that loads data for the lookup, so it contains a field _emailid_16chars_.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL server, you can write a lookup override query as below

```
SELECT 
COLUMN1 AS COL1,
COLUMN2 AS COL1,
SUBSTRING(COL_EMAIL_ID,len(COL_EMAIL_ID)-15,16) AS LAST_16CHAR_OF_EMAIL_ID,
..
FROM LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME
 <<WHERE CONDITIONS IF ANY>>
```

And, now try to compare your input port with LAST_16CHAR_OF_EMAIL_ID port from the lookup override. Always remember to alias your override columns and the order of the ports in your lookup transformation should be same as that in the select clause of your sql override

In case of Netezza or Oracle database,below substring statement should work

```
substr(COL_EMAIL_ID,length(COL_EMAIL_ID)-15,16)
```